# Getting uncought error: input is a void element tag while using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i fix this error:

```
input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input>Start editing to see some magic happen!</input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happening because an `input` should be a single self closed tag. If you want some descriptive text use a `label` or a `placeholder` like so :

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input
        placeholder = "Start editing to see some magic happen!"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```